# How do I save a date input from csv as a variable PYTHON

Tags: python

I need my program to take one cell in a csv that is a date and save it as a variable, then read the next cell in the column and save it as the next variable. The rest of the program does a calculation with the dates, but i am not sure how to save each date as a variable. (The part that is commented out is what it would look like if a user did the input themsef, but I would like it read in from the csv)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zh58N.png)

Comment: please add code here instead of an image

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert csv to numpy with:

```py
from numpy import genfromtxt
my_data = genfromtxt('my_file.csv', delimiter=',')
```

And then you can just iterate through the created array to get the elements. Be careful as how the delimiter is defined, here it's a coma, sometimes there isn't any, so just make sure you know how your csv data are delimited.